# Getting req.getParameter("concurid") value from some jsp page into inline java code into another jsp page and then pass it to servlet through button

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have made a travelrecords table in a jsp page and nowIi want to have an edit option to edit the travelstartdate and travelenddate as can be seen in [capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXmVA.png).

When I click on the edit option a form is popup:ed which only allows the user to edit travelstartdate and travelenddate and then apply with the new values as can be seen in [capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCn9d.png).

The popup form is getting respected concurid but when I click on the apply button the changes are not saved in the database as the button is not getting respected concurid value and thus not passing further to its servlet for a database update.

The popup form is the jsp page where I have used inline java code to get the concurid value from some other jsp page (which is cid and it's working).

But I am not able to use this cid variable or directly request.getParameter("concurid") inside button onclick function as this cid value has been called in the script <% %> tags.

In the servlet page I am getting concurid value by using String CONCURID=request.getParameter("cocurid");

How can I pass this value outside the script tags i.e. in the button, so that it can be sent to some servlet page for update in database?

```
                                 (POPUP.jsp)
    <html>
    <%@ page import = "java.io.*, 
    javax.servlet.*,java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.time.LocalDate" %>
    <body>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <form action="ServletEdit">
    <table style="float:left;color:white; font-family: 
         Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11.6px;font-weight:bold;" 
          border="4" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr bgcolor="#928E8E" style="border:1pt solid 
                black">
            <tr>
                <td>FULLNAME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FUNCTION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANAGER</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PURPOSE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PNAME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MEETING</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 29px;">REQDATE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 34px;">STARTDATE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 34px;">ENDDATE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 31px;">NUMDAYS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SOURCE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DEST</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CDATE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CID</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>REMARKS</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <% 
         try
         {    Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection
              ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","up78cp5317");
                String pd=request.getParameter("REQUESTDATE");
                String cid=request.getParameter("concurid");
                String query="select * from APPROVAL Where 
                CONCURID='"+cid+"'";
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                {
            %>
           <table style="float:left;color:white; 
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, 
            sans-serif; font-size:11.6px;font-weight:bold;" border="4" 
            cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" >
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("FULLNAME")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("FUNCTION")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("RESOURCEMANAGER")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("PURPOSEOFTRAVEL")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("PROJECTNAME")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("MEETINGDETAILS")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea rows="1" cols="30" 
                 name="RequestDate" type="date" readonly maxlength="100" 
                 class="textbox" style="width: 150px;" id="pick_date" 
                  onchange="cal()"><%=rs.getString("REQUESTDATE")%> 
                 </textarea></td>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function GetDays()
                    {
                     var dropdt = new 
                     Date(document.getElementById("drop_date").value);
                     var pickdt = new 
                     Date(document.getElementById("pick_date").value);
                     return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 
                     1000));
                    }
                    function cal()
                    {
                    if(document.getElementById("drop_date"))
                    {

                     document.getElementById("numdays3").value=GetDays();
                    }  
                    }
                </script>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="TravelStartDate" type="date" 
                 maxlength="100" class="textbox" style="width: 150px" 
                id="drop_date" onchange="cal()"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="TravelEndDate" type="date" maxlength="100" 
                style="width: 150px"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="numdays" type="text" maxlength="100" 
                readonly class="textbox" style="width: 150px" id="numdays3" 
                /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("TRAVELSOURCE") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("TRAVELDESTINATION") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("CONCURDATE") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("CONCURID") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("ANYREMARKS") %></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="sign" value="SIGNIN" 
         onclick="location.href='ServletEdit?CONCURID= 
         <%=request.getParameter("concurid")%>'" style="width:70px;                                  
            height:30px;
            margin-right:20%;
            border:none; 
            border-radius:2px; 
            font-size:13px; 
            font-weight:bold;">Apply</button>
        <%
            }
            %>
        <% 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            %>                  
        </article>
        </section>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
  <button type="submit" name="sign" value="SIGNIN" 
         onclick="location.href='ServletEdit?CONCURID= 
         <%=request.getParameter("concurid")%>'">Apply</button>
```

You can make an input field and keep it hidden ,also put this inside your form tag

```
<input type="text" name="concurid"  value="<%=request.getParameter("concurid")%>" hidden>
```

And call this directly using `request.getParameter("concurid")` in your `servlet` .Also your button will be like this

```
<button type="submit" name="sign" value="SIGNIN" >Apply</button>
```